# Django form-fields: Styling for Bootstrap without losing functionality?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-forms

So `form.as_p` in django gives a plain, yet very catered form, with field inputs matching the entity attribute type, like so:

[image]

Notice how `vintage` is a dropdown item, and so is `brand`. But then again, it's *very plain*.

I want to use bootstrap styling with the django form without losing the way django customizes each input type by the model attributes.

I have managed to achieve this:

[image]

By doing this in my `.pug` template:

```
                form(method="post" action=".")
                    | {% csrf_token %}
                    for field in da_form
                        div(class="form-group row")
                            label(class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 cold-sm-6 col-form-label") {{field.label_tag}}
                            div(class="col-lg-8 col-md-3 cold-sm-6")
                                input(class="form-control") {{field}}
                    input(class="form-control")(type="submit" value="submit")
```

But how can I ***both* get the style, and the catered form inputs** from django? In my current form all fields are simple input types.

Comment: your question is not clear. you want to use bootstrap in your form? or something else you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Exprator: Sorry, I've added another sentence. Basically this is what I want: Style django's forms with bootstrap (so adding `form-control` to class, etc...) but without losing the custom input type for fields (notice how vintage is a dropdown item, and so is brand)

Comment: what is this pug template? why are you not using the normal html and easily you can do it

Comment: @Exprator pug is formerly known as jade, and it's a faster way to write HTML. If you can show me how to do it in HTML, I can write it in pug.

Comment: ok then i am giving the django template language change it to pug and tell if it works

Comment: see if you can get this to pug, as this works properly without change the type of any field in django template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
{% for fields in form.visible_fields %}
<div label={{ fields.label_tag }} class="bootstrap class" id="your need">
<div class="your need">{{ fields }} </div>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hmmm, bootstrap recommends [using forms like so](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) in order to get the styling to work properly. When I don't do `form-group` as in their example my form gets jumbled. The main problem right now is that while you're doing `<div class="your need">{{ fields }} </div>`, I need to do something like `<input class="your need">...` and that completely removes the django form funcitonality.

Comment: yes obviously it will, in case of dropdown you are substituting it with an input field thus it gets rendered in the form,

Comment: So my only options are either to style the `div` manually to match bootstraps CSS definiton for `input`, or simply not use bootstrap style forms...?

Comment: you want to style the fields right? then why you need input? those are all provided by django, just use any tag whether p or div or span, and put the bootstrap class inside it and its done

Comment: You are right. Actually my question should have been, how to add a class to an a `{{ field}}` because the **type** of field is auto-loaded by django. If I manage to add `class="control-form"` to each field (whether it's input, select, or anything elese) then my form looks good. I can't figure out how to do that though.